# CGI/Perl script creating a customized signature file

Tags: perl, cgi

I have this working somewhat.
I have a cgi file that has the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
$cgi = new CGI;

open (IMAGE, "ts.jpg");
$size = -s "ts.jpg";
read IMAGE, $data, $size;
close (IMAGE);

print $cgi->header(-type=>'image/jpeg'), $data;

exit;
```

This displays my image file corrrectly.
However, I want a user to be able to add 2 lines of text over the image through a web form to generate a new jpeg each time. Here is the URL: http://elearning.cpma.ca/signature.html

What am I missing in my cgi file that would allow me to re-publish to screen a new jpeg file with the 2 lines of text appearing on it when I click on the "Add Text" Button?

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: The way your question is worded makes it sound like you expect someone to do all the work for you and provide a code dump. (I'm not saying that that was your intent, but that's how it sounds.) As such, your post is likely to be downvoted and/or closed. I would recommend looking into [GD](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD) to overlay text on an image.

Comment: Hi Matt. I'm just looking for direction on how to make it refresh and a text over an image. I never used GD before. I will give it a try.

Comment: Adding a watermark / signature is easy with Image::Magick. See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=369366 for an almost complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create what I wanted through a Readme provided by alvarotrigo on GitHUb [TextPainter](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/blob/master/textPainter/README.md)

I was required to make some minor code changes in order to make it work properly - however, it was very easy to implement.
No CGI required. See [SignatureFile](http://elearning.cpma.ca/Signature/signaturefile.php) for the final outcome of my image.
Thank you to all who responded to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an image processing library. You'll see lots of recommendations for [GD](https://metacpan.org/release/GD) or [ImageMagick](https://metacpan.org/release/PerlMagick), but I think I'd use [Imager](https://metacpan.org/release/Imager), as it's newer and a little easier to use.

A few general suggestions for improvements to your code.

1. Always use `strict` and `warnings` in your code.
2. Declare variables with `my` (`my $cgi = ...`).
3. The `new CGI` syntax is potentially problematic. Use `CGI->new` instead.
4. Use three-arg open and lexical filehandles (`open my $image_fh, '<', 'ts.jpg')`).
5. Always check the return code from `open` (`open my $image_fh, '<', 'ts.jpg') or die $!`).